# Contact Form 7 CiviCRM integration not connecting to remote CiviCRM website

Tags: contacts, forms, form-processor, individual

I'm trying to connect my a form to a remote CiviCRM website. To do that I'm following this tutorial using FormProcessor Contact Form 7 and Contact Form 7 CiviCRM integration https://docs.civicrm.org/formprocessor/en/latest/sign-up-newsletter-wordpress/

My CiviCRM Contact Form 7 Settings is filled correctly (with the path for wordpress, the api_key and site_key are correct). My contact form field are similar to the FormProcessor input and should be ok, I tested everything on RESTer chrome extension and it work the contact is added on my remote CiviCRM but when using the extension with the form it doesn't.

In Contact Form 7 "CiviCRM" tab my entity is set to FormProcessor and my Action has the correct name. I didn't filled the "params" field.

Wordfence is disabled

Comment: What happens after you submit the form?  Any message?

Comment: I get a message confirming the "info has been sent" but it hasn't been up on my CiviCRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Caldera Form instead of Contact Form 7 on the remote website, I added the plugins "Connector to CiviCRM with CiviMcRestFace" and
"Integration of CiviCRM's Form Processor with Caldera Forms". In the parameters CiviMcRestFace Connections there is the same interface as CiviCRM Contact Form 7 Settings but the path you have to input is different. When you create or edit the form with Caldera don't forget to add a processor in the processors tab, and make sure this processor connect to the Form Processor you created on CiviCRM.

Comment: unfortunately Caldera Forms are not going to be a solution in the future

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and what worked for me (thanks to advice from Jaap Jansma) was setting the **CiviCRM path** in **Settings > CiviCRM Contact Form 7 Settings** to
**wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest**
(not the older path that is shown in most of the documentation).

Any incompatibilities in the submitted data can also cause silent failure though, so you might have to go back to basics to solve it.

Unfortunately Caldera Forms are being discontinued at the end of the year (2021) and replaced by Ninja forms (much more expensive and doesn't have CiviCRM integration yet, though it's promised).

Comment: might civi's own SearchKit and AFFORM come to the rescue?